# Imagick annotateimage corrupted text

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I have been using imagemagick successfully with the script unchanged since 18 months.

I have background images with no text and I used the imagemagick function
$img->annotateimage($draw,$X,$Y,0,$Text) to write text on those images.
It worked fine.
Today however I noticed the text is rendering incorrectly:
[image]

The filled "p" and the filled "ø" are not from my script. The line from the base of the P to the "ø" is not from my script. The change in opacity of the text is not from my script.

Is anyone aware of anything on the server side which could be causing such odd behaviour?

Any help would be appreciated.

David

Comment: Did your ISP update ImageMagick or Imagick on our server? Some versions of PHP/Imagick may not be compatible with ImageMagick 7. Are you using ImageMagick 6 or 7.

Comment: I suspect that my ISP has done something but after speaking with them, I am no further ahead. They were rude and unhelpful when I called them :-(.    How can I find out which version of ImageMagick is running? On the ISP configuration page does not provide the version number. I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: Just tried changing the server configuration to PHP7.0 and the result is unchanged.

Comment: echo "<pre>";
system("convert -version");  
echo "</pre>";

Comment: There may be multiple versions of ImageMagick on the system. You can find out via type -a magick, if on IM 7 and type -a convert on IM 6 placed into a system() or exec() call. I would not know how to tell which version is linked to the Imagick.

Comment: Woops did not notice the Op was using Imagick: $version = Imagick::getVersion(); 
echo 'API version number: '.$version['versionNumber'].'<br />'; 
echo 'API version string: '.$version['versionString'].'<br />';

Comment: Thanks for the tip. API version number: 1673
API version string: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-15 http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: Does the 2017-07-15 date indicate something new is on the server side in the last 5 days?  Sounds like an indication that the problem lies with a change the ISP has made.

Comment: Possibly they upgraded ImageMagick but didn't upgrade also Imagick, which is a big no-non. I added checks to Imagick to prevent that from happening without notice....but it could still happen.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this same problem...
I heard back from the ISP today and the problem now seems to have been resolved.
So, it seems it was a version problem of some sort on the ISP's side.